# What happens when a GlobalKTable is loaded from a topic with the same key in different topics?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We had a compacted topic with a single partition, and we added one new partition to it.

We did not re-partition existing data - meaning the events loaded before the addition of the new partitions are still in the partition `0`. And new events are stored according to the standard policy, as expected: all events with the same key into the same partition.

We are currently in a case like this one:

```
Partition    Offset    Timestamp      Key         Value
0            586       1545388284240  COD_ISIN    AAA
1            983       1551800369978  COD_ISIN    BBB
1            1141      1556526044144  COD_ISIN    CCC
```

When I load this topic in a `GlobalKTable`, the value in the store is `AAA`. And we obviously expected to have `CCC` as current value.

```
GlobalKTable<String, JsonNode> storeDatacatalog = builder.globalTable(TOPIC, consumed,  Materialized.as(STORE_DATACATALOG));

KStream<String, JsonNode> inEvent = builder.stream(OTHER_TOPIC, consumed);

inEvent = inEvent.transform(
    new TransformerSupplier<String, JsonNode, KeyValue<String, JsonNode>>() {

        @Override
        public Transformer<String, JsonNode, KeyValue<String, JsonNode>> get() {

            return new Transformer<String, JsonNode, KeyValue<String, JsonNode>>() {

                private ProcessorContext context;
                private KeyValueStore<String, JsonNode> dataCatalogueState;

                @Override
                public void init(ProcessorContext context) {

                    this.context = context;
                    this.dataCatalogueState = (KeyValueStore<String, JsonNode>) context.getStateStore(STORE_DATACATALOG);

                    LOGGER.debug("Content of dataCatalogueState: ");
                    KeyValueIterator<String, JsonNode> allDc = this.dataCatalogueState.all();

                    JsonNode valueForIsin = null;

                    while (allDc.hasNext()) {
                        try {
                            KeyValue<String, JsonNode> next = allDc.next();
                            LOGGER.debug(" | " + next.key + " : " + next.value);
                            if ("COD_ISIN".equals(next.key)) 
                                valueForIsin = next.value;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            LOGGER.debug("exc" , e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    LOGGER.info(" COD_ISIN ---> " + valueForIsin);
                }

                @Override
                public void close() {
                }

                @Override
                public KeyValue<String, JsonNode> transform(String key, JsonNode value) {
                    return new KeyValue<>(key, value);
                }

                //@Override
                public KeyValue<String, JsonNode> punctuate(long timestamp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    }
)
```

**How does the `GlobalKTable` build its state? Is it based on the `Offset` or on the `Timestamp`?** 
Does it internally stick the key to the first partition where the the key is found?

I know how to workaround (purge the topic and populate again - the partition strategy will be applied). But I am curious about how it works internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GlobalKTable` assume the data is partitioned by key. Hence, if you have records with the same key in different partitions, there is no guarantee in which order record will be applied. Order is only guaranteed per partition. Besides this, atm, updates are based on offsets only within a partition.

Using your example from above, the order could be

- AAA, BBB, CCC
- BBB, AAA, CCC
- BBB, CCC, AAA

It's only guaranteed, that BBB will be applied before CCC.

Comment: Thank you Matthias. So it's the "order per  partition guarantee" standard rule that works here. Do you think it would be useful to upgrade the way `GlobalKTable`s are loaded - in order to take care of the timestamp only? (I have no final opinion on this subject. It's only an open question. 1-Pro: GlobalKTable already differ from KTable in the way data is loaded from all the partitions // 2-Cons: it's very unusual to have messages with the same key in different topics.)

Comment: My personal believe is, that both `KTable` and `GlobalKTable` should consider timestamps for updates -- to do this, we need to store the timestamp of the last update though, what is not supported yet. In fact, storing timestamps will be part of upcoming 2.3 release (cf https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-258%3A+Allow+to+Store+Record+Timestamps+in+RocksDB) -- however, for `GlobalKTables` this would only resolve the issue partly: you could still have to records from different partitions with the same timestamp.